# maximal subgroup of the general linear group

Tags: algebraic-groups, orthogonal-matrices, maximal-subgroup, classical-groups

Maybe I'm being silly.

As algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic not $2$, is the conformal orthogonal group $CO_{2n}$ a maximal subgroup of $GL_{2n}$(or $CO_{2n+1}$ a maximal subgroup of $GL_{2n+1}$)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space, and let $Q \in \text{Sym}^2(V^*)$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. Then we set
$$
\mathrm{O}(V) = \{g \in \mathrm{GL}(V): Q(g(v),g(w)) = Q(v,w), \forall v, w \in V\}
$$
and $\mathrm{GO}(V)= Z(\mathrm{GL}(V)).\mathrm{O}(V)$ (the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ which preserves $Q$ up to a scalar multiple).

If $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ contains a subgroup $H$ with

$$
\mathrm{GO}(V) = N_{\mathrm{GL}(V)}(\mathrm{O}(V))<H\leq \mathrm{GL}(V),
$$
then at the level of Lie algebras, $\mathrm{Lie}(H)$ would be an $\mathrm{O}(V)$-subrepresentation of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ which strictly contained $\mathrm{Lie}(\mathrm{O}(V))\oplus \mathsf k.I$, and therefore (identifying $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ with $V\otimes V$ as a $\mathrm{O}(V)$-representation, it would have to be all of $V\otimes V$, since I think $V\otimes V$ decomposes as a direct sum of $3$ irreducible representations $\bigwedge^2(V)\oplus \mathsf k.Q \oplus H$ of $\mathrm{O}(V)$.

I'm not 100% sure that works outside characteristic zero, but I think the weights are small enough that it has a good chance!

Comment: Thank you for your time. May I ask what is your definition of $O(V)$?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've updated the answer to try and clarify that. Let me know if anything else needs clarification!